# FlowOver Stack App

Tags: app, android, stackoverflow

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: App screenshot]

### About

A Stack Overflow Client App where Developers can search and look out questions as well as solutions to problems posted on Stack Overflow. They can as well run a search on it. It helps developers get solutions to problems on the run especially when they don't have access to their PC

#### Download

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.josycom.mayorjay.flowoverstack

#### Platform

Android

### Contact

Creator:

https://github.com/mayorJAY

https://twitter.com/mayorjay1

Contributor:

https://github.com/mbobiosio

https://twitter.com/cazewonder

### Code

Written with Java

It can be found here: https://github.com/mayorJAY/FlowOverStack

To contribute, just make a PR. It's that simple!